# Converting wav to mp3 - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Is there a way to convert WAV files to MP3 in ASP.NET? I have heard of LAME but haven't found any examples for a web application. Also, I wasn't sure if it can be commercially used.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding commercial usage: http://lame.sourceforge.net/license.txt There may also be patent restrictions in your country.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to use this? Where can I find the correct Lame.dll for me and how do I tell which to use?
How and where can this be added into an existing asp.net web application?
What files need to be placed where?
How do I properly refference the files?
How do I properly populate the parameters?
What is the waitFLag Parameter? .. How do I get this going?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this code:

```
public void mciConvertWavMP3(string fileName, bool waitFlag) {
        string outfile= "-b 32 --resample 22.05 -m m \""+pworkingDir+fileName + "\" \"" + pworkingDir+fileName.Replace(".wav",".mp3")+"\"";
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi=new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName="\""+pworkingDir+"lame.exe"+"\"";
        psi.Arguments=outfile;
        psi.WindowStyle=System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        System.Diagnostics.Process p=System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
        if (waitFlag)
        {
        p.WaitForExit();
        }
 }
```

Comment: I can do this from within a web app?

Comment: Yes, it will run on your server, so your server needs to have Lame installed.

Comment: it's .NET, so just add this function to your library and call it.

Comment: works fine. quickest solution. lame exe taken from here http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php

thanks afftee, you saved me couple of hours!! :)

Comment: Is there a way to use lame to stream the mp3 file while it's encoding ?

Comment: (Four years later.)  Yup, works a treat.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx) on CodeProject showing how to compress a wave file in C# using the Lame codec. It is a managed wrapper around the codec.